# Weird Facebook font problem on Firefox

Tags: firefox, fonts, facebook

I am using Firefox 23 and Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity.

Today, I was dealing with font configuration to make them look like sharper and less blurry. After some mambo jambo, Facebook started to look like this:

[image]

or like this:

[image]

I believe this is something related to msttcorefonts or Ubuntu restricted extras or some terminal commands such as "fc-cache". I do not have this problem for any other webpage. I tried to reset font settings via MyUnity. I tried to create a new Firefox profile. I started Firefox add-ons disabled. None of them worked. I have been trying to find a solution to this but could not come across one at anywhere so I decided to ask here.

Comment: Do you need `msstcorefonts`? If not just removing it and run `fc-cache -f -v` should do the trick.

Comment: Ben - you appear to have multiple accounts.  please click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page to request that your accounts are merged.  Once done you will be available to edit your question again with any replies.

Comment: @fossfreedom The accounts appear all to be unregistered. Can unregistered accounts be merged via the *contact us* link, or is it necessary to register an account first?

Comment: SE like a registered account to merge to - however, they have "other means" to determine if two accounts are the same, so it is possible to merge unregistered accounts.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem. There were no fonts visible in sites like Facebook, Hotmail... I managed to solve the problem the following way:

- Firefox → Preferences... → Content → Advanced: Uncheck the box that allows other programs to choose the fonts for the page.

It's not the best solution, but however it works... I guess it's a bug with Firefox 30.0 - I hadn't any problem with Firefox 29... (I've noticed this problem after I updated Firefox to version 30.0 and LibreOffice to version 4.2.4.2)

Answer (score 0):

I did not know what caused this problem, but I solved it by simply copying fonts folder from Xubuntu which I had in another partition to Ubuntu. These folders are at `/usr/share/fonts`